# Results for SQL Server query unexpected

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to sort through a large table, we'll call this Table1, using values from another table, we'll call this Table2, to filter the results. Unfortunately my query results are showing values that don't match my filter, values found in Table2.

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 on Table1.ColumnX = Table2.ColumnX
AND    Table1.DateAddedToMarket >= '2018-01-01' 
AND    Table1.DateAddedToMarket < '2018-02-01' 
UNION
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 on Table1.ColumnX = Table2.ColumnY
AND    Table1.DateAddedToMarket >= '2018-01-01' 
AND    Table1.DateAddedToMarket < '2018-02-01' 
ORDER BY Table1.DateAddedToMarket DESC
```

This is what Table2 looks like:

```
+--------+--------------+
|ColumnX |    ColumnY   |
+--------+--------------+
| 872510 |       879962 |
| 872514 |       879963 |
| 872511 |              |
| 872515 |              |
| 872512 |              |
| 879529 |              |
| 872513 |              |
| 879530 |              |
| 879959 |              |
| 879960 |              |
| 879961 |              |
+--------+--------------+
```

This is what Table1 looks like:

```
+---------+-------------------+
|ColumnX  | DateAddedToMarket |
+---------+-------------------+
|         |                   |
| 872510  | 2018-01-01        |
| 872514  | 2018-01-02        |
| 872511  | 2018-01-03        |
| 872515  | 2018-01-04        |
| 872512  | 2018-01-05        |
| 879529  | 2018-03-01        |
| 872513  | 2018-03-02        |
| 879530  | 2018-03-03        |
| 879959  | 2018-03-04        |
| 879960  | 2018-01-05        |
| 879961  | 2018-01-06        |
| 879962  | 2018-01-07        |
| 879963  | 2018-01-08        |
| 379964  | 2018-01-09        |
| 379978  | 2018-01-10        |
| 379979  | 2018-01-11        |
| 379980  | 2018-03-04        |
| 513907  | 2018-03-05        |
| 517156  | 2018-03-06        |
| 519984  | 2018-03-07        |
| 547211  | 2018-03-08        |
| 547270  | 2018-03-09        |
| 552874  | 2018-03-10        |
| 552952  | 2018-03-11        |
|         |                   |
+---------+-------------------+
```

The date filter works perfectly; however, there will be some values in the results which are not found on Table2.

Expected result:

```
+---------+-------------------+
|ColumnX  | DateAddedToMarket |
+---------+-------------------+
|         |                   |
| 872510  | 2018-01-01        |
| 872514  | 2018-01-02        |
| 872511  | 2018-01-03        |
| 872515  | 2018-01-04        |
| 872512  | 2018-01-05        |
| 879960  | 2018-01-05        |
| 879961  | 2018-01-06        |
| 879962  | 2018-01-07        |
| 879963  | 2018-01-08        |
+---------+-------------------+
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `UNION` given you're executing the same query twice?

Comment: Given this example, what is the expected result ?

Comment: @PedroMartins I have added the expected result.

Comment: What extra values?

Answer (score 0):

Take the filters out of the on clause and put them in the where clause.

```
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 on Table1.ColumnX = Table2.ColumnX
WHERE Table1.DateAddedToMarket >= '2018-01-01' 
AND    Table1.DateAddedToMarket < '2018-02-01' 
UNION
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 on Table1.ColumnX = Table2.ColumnY
WHERE Table1.DateAddedToMarket >= '2018-01-01' 
AND    Table1.DateAddedToMarket < '2018-02-01' 
ORDER BY Table1.DateAddedToMarket DESC
```

Comment: This gives me the same results as my original query.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to do it without a union.

```
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 
WHERE Table1.DateAddedToMarket >= '2018-01-01' 
AND    Table1.DateAddedToMarket < '2018-02-01' 
AND  (Table1.ColumnX in (select columnX from table2)
     or Table1.columnX (in select columnY from table2))
ORDER BY Table1.DateAddedToMarket DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using UNION, while you just need a join to do it in one run. Like this :

```
SELECT 
    t1.ColumnX, 
    t1.DateAddedToMarket
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ColumnX = t1.ColumnX OR t2.ColumnY = t1.ColumnX
WHERE 
    t1.DateAddedToMarket BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01'
```

OUTPUT

```
| ColumnX | DateAddedToMarket |
|---------|-------------------|
|  872510 |        2018-01-01 |
|  872514 |        2018-01-02 |
|  872511 |        2018-01-03 |
|  872515 |        2018-01-04 |
|  872512 |        2018-01-05 |
|  879960 |        2018-01-05 |
|  879961 |        2018-01-06 |
|  879962 |        2018-01-07 |
|  879963 |        2018-01-08 |
```

Fiddle : [Live Preview](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb1ff/2)

Comment: Maybe this is where I'm running into issues, 379964, 379978 and 379979 should not be in the output. I only want values that match Table2. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @EmilioPagan-Yourno I've updated the query, I just saw your excepted output.

Comment: You should add this info to your question - you've explained the input, your expected output, but not your current output.

Comment: select distinct